# How do I install ANTLR IDE with Eclipse Juno and PDT (PHP)

Tags: java, eclipse, antlr, antlr3, eclipse-pdt

I develop in both PHP and Java. Eclipse PDT appears to require DLTK 4.0, which it has no problem getting. ANTLR IDE appears to require DLTK3. I've tried copying the plugins 3.0 into my Eclipse plugins / features directory:

http://download.eclipse.org/technology/dltk/downloads/drops/R3.0/S-3.0.1-201108261011/

This worked on a machine without PDT, but I can't get it to work when I have PDT.

I have also tried using the marketplace, but I get the same dependency errors.

Note I'm on 64bit Linux.

Answer (score 3):

Try to add the DLTK 3.0 repository and then install ANTLR again, so maybe Eclipse can fetch the plugin and be able to manage the 2 versions of DLTK installed.

The repository is:

```
http://download.eclipse.org/technology/dltk/updates-dev/3.0-stable/
```

Comment: Thanks, Enrico. This seems to work. After adding the 3.0 repository, I cannot select DLTK to install it since I have a newer version. However, when trying to install ANTLR IDE it seems to pick up the 3.0 requirements and grab it out of the correct repository anyway. =)

Comment: Further testing shows this actually is not working =(. DLTK 3.0 conflicts with PDT