# PDT on eclipse juno won't work, how to properly install it?

Tags: php, eclipse, eclipse-juno, eclipse-pdt

I have on my windows 7 machine eclipse juno installed, I downloaded the PDT (php development tools) and installed it. But when I try to create a php project via wizard I cannot find an option for php project.

Here's my screenshot where PDT is really installed in my eclipse juno.

[image]

Here is the wizard of my eclipse juno, as you can see no option for PHP.
[image]

Am I missing something? Did I improperly installed the PDT, if so how do I properly install it? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Did you actually install PDT? Your screenshot shows it as available for installation.

Comment: It is already installed. The icon (with SDK) is in grey it means it is installed. The other ones is installed also. I tried checking them and hitting next but eclipse complains that it is already installed.

Comment: Hm, this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12810596/how-do-i-install-antlr-ide-with-eclipse-juno-and-pdt-php ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally installed it successfully, I read pageman's eclipse forum link (third link in pageman's answer) and somehow got a clue what I have done wrong. I think the problem is that I installed both the PHP Development Tools (PDT) and PHP Development Tools (PDT) SDK Feature under the **programming languages** category. I downloaded the latest copy of eclipse and installed the PHP Development Tools (PDT) SDK Feature under the category **Web,XML,Java EE and OSGi Enterprise Development**.

[image]

Now the php project wizard is present.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try use from this source `http://download.eclipse.org/tools/pdt/updates/release`. It seems due to updates on releases stage.

Instead of eclipse source, put Google source `http://dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/4.2` for Eclipse 3.8/4.2 (Juno).

Comment: Still won't work, those things that you have given is already installed in my eclipse juno. Those are the same packages in my eclipse.

Comment: Sorry but I cannot see the PDT(PHP Development Tools) in this repository, all I can see is google development related eclipse plug ins.